# Acessar a pasta data/data no DDMS

Tags: android, android-studio, windows

Não estou conseguindo acessar a pasta data/data no ddms no Windows. Eu consigo ver todas pasta mais algumas como o data/data não consigo acessar. Alguém tem uma solução?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode ser algum problema de permissão, você precisa ter um dispositivo com root para ver esta pasta. Se seu dispositivo tiver **root**, tente os seguintes passos:

1. Abra o prompt de comando
2. Navegue até a pasta onde está o seu adb
3. Entre com o comando `adb shell`
4. Entre com o comando `su`
5. Se o comando `su` apresentar algum erro de permissão, execute o passo **6**, se não continue para o passo **7**.
6. Navegue no seu dispositivo em: `Configurações` -> `Opções de Desenvolvedor` -> `Acesso root` -> Marque a opção `Aplicativos e ADB`. Execute o passo **4** novamente.
7. Pressione para permitir no diálogo que abrir no seu dispositivo
8. Entre com o comando `chmod 777 /data /data/data /data/data/com.application.package /data/data/com.application.package/*`
9. Verifique se você já consegue acessar a pasta pelo **DDMS**

Não esqueça de alterar `com.application.package` pelo seu pacote original.

---

**Resposta original aqui:**

[Android eclipse DDMS - Can't access data/data/ on phone to pull files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8896049/5263999)

Comment: Esse processo é no sistema operacional Windows mesmo? Se for vou tentar mais tarde.obrigado.

Comment: Sim Jaison, pelo prompt de comando do windows. Se resolver ou não, só não esqueça de nos contar, boa sorte

Comment: Deu certo, consegui ter acesso a pasta. Valeu muito obrigado. Minha outra dúvida se é possível debugar um app do celular em execução e monitorar a memória.ou tenho que usar o avd?